# Question about differentiation of tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, differentiation

According to Arnab Rai Choudhuri, Astrophysics for physicists Page 363:

$$\frac{\partial \overline A^i}{\partial \overline x^l}=\frac{\partial A^k}{\partial x^m}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l}\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}+A^k\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l}\frac{\partial^2\overline x^i}{\partial x^m \partial x^k} \, ,$$

follows directly from:

$$\overline A^i=A^k\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k} \, .$$

I can't seem to understand why, any insight?

Comment: Isn't this directly the chain rule of partial differentiation in application?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Well, I did look at the chain rule of partial differentiation but it doesen't seem like that is the answer. It did not produce the above equation for me (maybe I used it wrong). I have mostly stared at it and coming up with nothing...

Comment: Because there is a second term it probably has something to do with the product rule  but I can't make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial \overline A^{i}}{\partial \overline x^l} $ = $\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l} \frac{\partial \overline A^{i}}{\partial x^m} $ = $\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^m}(A^k \frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}) $ = $ \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l} \frac{\partial A^k}{\partial x^m} \frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial  x^k} $ + $A^k \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \overline x^l} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^m} (\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial  x^k}) \\$ 
I find this is an easy way to do it.

Comment: That was awesome, I like that answer! Thanks so very much!

Comment: No problem! Great that it helped.

Answer (score 3):

The product rule gives 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\overline A^i}{\partial\overline{x}^\ell}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{x}^\ell}\left(A^k\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}\right) \\
&=\frac{\partial A^k}{\partial \overline{x}^\ell} \frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}+A^k\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{x}^\ell}\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}
\end{align*}

but recall the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\ell}=\sum_j \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^\ell}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}$$

Apply this exact identity with $f=\frac{\partial \overline x^i}{\partial x^k}$ and $y^j=x^j$ to get the desired answer.

Answer (score -5):

A tensor is a multidimensonal matrix, so a tensor of 3rd rank is just a cube. You cannot differentiate a cube or other random geometric objects, only functions !

Comment: You can pick a basis, and then the components of your tensor are scalar functions, which can be differentiated.

Comment: But you cannot pick a basis for geometry or else we could classify every possible calabi Yau and win the nobel price!